# docker service exposes port on all workers in swarm

Tags: python, nginx, docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get a docker service up using the python SDK. My service is a nginx container that's supposed to bind the container 80 port to the machine 80 port. The nginx config has a redirect clause for all http traffic to https.

When launching the service, i'm using the following parameters:

```
    params = {
        'endpoint_spec': docker.types.EndpointSpec(ports={80: 80}),
        'name': name,
        'hostname': name,
        'image': NGINX_IMAGE_NAME,
        'networks': [NETWORK_NAME],
        'mounts': ['/home/ubuntu/.ssh/certs:/certs:ro'],
        'log_driver': 'syslog',
        'log_driver_options': {'syslog-address': 'udp://localhost:514'},
        'constraints': ['node.labels.environment==test']
    }
api.services.create(**params)
```

The behaviour i was expecting was the 80 port exposed on all nodes that have the environment labes set to test. What i got instead is the 80 port open on all nodes in the docker swarm. Is this intended ? Can one restrict the binding to a particular node?

EDIT:

Apparently [the docker ingress network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/) is responsible for my dilemma. Any hints on how to disable this particular behavior?